# 3D Touch Peek Swipe Like Mail

Tags: ios, swift2, uikit

Using the 3D Touch Peek and Pop functionality, what is the most effective way of mimicking the capability depicted below (to swipe the "peeked" content side-to-side to perform an action)? The screenshot below comes from the iOS native Mail app.

[image: Mail Swipe 3D Touch - Unread]
[image: Mail Swipe 3D Touch - Trash]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that unless Facebook is approved to use private APIs, their app allows you to slide side to side on albums to see more images, so there are apps in the App Store with that functionality.

Comment: @DougSmith You can reimplement the entire UIKit 3D Touch functionality yourself, including this. Facebook has implemented it using manually listening to the force gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

You can replicate this effect on iOS 10. There's a new set of APIs called [`UIPreviewInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipreviewinteraction) and [`UIPreviewInteractionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipreviewinteractiondelegate) that enable custom presentation for peek/pop interactions. I highly recommend watching [A Peek at 3D Touch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/228/) from this year's WWDC.

**Original Answer**

Looking at the [iOS Runtime Headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers), there's a class called `UIPreviewPresentationController`. That's the controller responsible for *peeks*. Inside it, there are references to objects called `leadingPreviewAction` and `trailingPreviewAction`. These have corresponding properties that deal with edge constraints and centers. Judging by use of the terms *leading* and *trailing* (as in Auto Layout), these may correspond to left/right action items.

This is speculation, but I think these related private classes (`_UIPreviewQuickActionView`) control the behavior you're looking for. Those are unavailable right now.

Likewise, the documentation for `UIPreviewAction` says:

> A preview action, or peek quick action, is displayed below a peek **when a user swipes the peek upward**. A peek quick action typically selects a deep link to your app and has a title, a style, and a handler.

Comment: And to answer your question "what is the most effective way of mimicking the capability", you'd end up recreating the functionality like @DougSmith said. I'd start here (https://github.com/marmelroy/PeekPop) for ideas on how to do that.

Comment: Through response, thank you! The information about the iOS Runtime Headers is especially interesting, I haven't run into those before. That definitely helps everything make more sense @Chris.

Answer (score 2):

To use **Peek Quick Actions**, your detailledViewControler (or whatever you named it) should override `previewActionItems` like that:

```
lazy var previewActions: [UIPreviewActionItem] = {
        func previewActionForTitle(title: String, style: UIPreviewActionStyle = .Default) -> UIPreviewAction {
            return UIPreviewAction(title: title, style: style) { previewAction, viewController in
                guard let detailViewController = viewController as? DetailViewController,
                          item = detailViewController.detailItemTitle else { return }

                print("\(previewAction.title) triggered from `DetailViewController` for item: \(item)")
            }
        }

        let action1 = previewActionForTitle("Default Action")
        let action2 = previewActionForTitle("Destructive Action", style: .Destructive)

        let subAction1 = previewActionForTitle("Sub Action 1")
        let subAction2 = previewActionForTitle("Sub Action 2")
        let groupedActions = UIPreviewActionGroup(title: "Sub Actions…", style: .Default, actions: [subAction1, subAction2] )

        return [action1, action2, groupedActions]
    }()


override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    return previewActions
}
```

You can find the whole code here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ViewControllerPreviews/ViewControllerPreviewsUsingtheUIViewControllerpreviewingAPIs.zip

Comment: This definitely gets me pointed in the right direction, but the code provided in the link doesn't seem to be able to swipe side-to-side once 3D Touch is used on any of those 3 rows like the mail app can. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe there is no way of achieving what you want with public API. Simply because public API is just about 2 or 3 methods and doesn't offers any options other than the `UIPreviewActionItem` which have only 3 "styles".
I believe Apple is keeping this one for itself...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. It would be nice to see more documentation on that. If you can find concrete information on it I'd be happy to award the bounty to you. Thanks for your thoughts so far.

Comment: I am downvoting this because it is not what was asked. It answers something, but not the question.

Comment: @LeoNatan well my answer is a bit old, and at that time there was no other answer anyway :p